# I want to compare 2 decimals to see which one is greater

Tags: javascript

I want to compare 2 decimals to see which one is greater.

This doesn't seem to be working for decimals and only works for integers (e.g. 1 > 2) and doesn't work for floats (1.67 > 1.98).

**This is my example that doesn't work:**

```
this.testOrder = (valA, valB): boolean => {
    const radix = 10;
    return parseInt(valA, radix) > parseInt(valB, radix);
};
```

Comment: `parseInt(1.67,10) = 2` and `parseInt(1.98, 10) = 2`. You should use `parseFloat()`

Comment: Well, yes, because `parseInt()` just discards everything after the period.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

`parseInt` takes only the integer part of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
this.testOrder = (valA, valB): boolean => {
    const radix = 10;
    return parseFloat(valA, radix) > parseFloat(valB, radix);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()):

```
this.testOrder = (valA, valB): boolean => {
  return +valA > +valB;
};
```

Example:

```js
var a = +'1.67',
    b = +'1.98';

console.log('a:', a);
console.log('b:', b);

console.log('boolean result (a > b):', a > b);
```